# In focframework, Hide the "Word printing" and "Email Sending" buttons in the Printing layout selection

Tags: java

I am using [focframework](https://github.com/FOC-framework/framework) to develop a web application.

When I click on the printing button in a form, I get the list of the available jasper printing layouts. Next to each layout I have 3 buttons to print it in different formats:

- "PDF" button: to print the report as PDF
- "MS Word" button: to export the report as Microsoft Word
- "Send Email" button: to send the report by email

[image]

Is there a way to hide the "Word" and or the "Email" Buttons?

Answer (score 1):

By default "MS Word" and "Send EMail" are active. you can disable them on one of 2 levels:

1- The whole application by adding these 2 lines to your **config.properties** file:

```
reportingLayout.wordExport=0
reportingLayout.emailSend=0
```

2- The current form only by adding in [Your Form].xml in the [ValidationSettings] tag the related attributes (**reportPrintAsWord**, **reportSendEMail**) like bellow:

```
<ValidationSettings withApply="true" withPrint="true" reportPrintAsWord="false" reportSendEMail="false" />
```